# Как правьнее писать js скрипт в Сервлете

Tags: javascript, java, java-ee, jsp

Есть JSP-файл с описанием HTML, в нем есть js-скрипты: ajax и все такое.

Что лучше оставить их там или создать для них js-файл и обращатся так?

Comment: Естественно, лучше по возможности разделять HTML и JS.

Comment: Думаю чтоб небыло слишком мнного кода на джсп а как насчет скорости?не будет отражаться?

Comment: Как удобней - так и делайте. Если кода не особо много и/или больше никто не будет дописывать и читать код - можно и в один файл все.
На разные удобно разделять, когда команда пишет, когда много кода, что бы не путаться.

Comment: Понятно милый друг спасибо вем

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Js лучше хранить отдельно (как картинки и стили). Если объем у js большой (и файлов  много), то лучше его минифицировать и объединить в один js.

Comment: Понятно в принципе я так и думал . Но хотел уточнить вдруг это на что-то отрицательно повлияет

Comment: @elik часто front-end пишут на языке отличным от java. И соответственно использую совершенно другие  методики и инструменты.